# Does the power of internal links vary depending on the quantity of them on page?

Tags: seo, links, pagerank, link-juice, internal-links

Would it be possible for one to strengthen certain internal links by getting rid of the excess ones? I am aware of the old advice of some google employee which went by the lines of hundred being a reasonable number, but it would still strike me as a better decision for the internal links to be stronger as they get smaller in quantity. I'd be quite glad if one could explain.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the quantity of internal links is that important anymore. The 100 link rule has been removed from the Google guidelines. On sites like Wikipedia you can pretty clearly see that this rule isn't followed and they rank very well.

Personally, I link to anything on my site that is related to the topic I'm talking about. Granted the 'link juice' that is passed from one page to another is diminished when there are more links but on the other hand a Google will have less information to go on if there are only a couple of links on a page.

This article on Backlinko is quite interesting if you'd like more information.
https://backlinko.com/hub/seo/internal-links

Answer (score 1):

The number of internal links per page tends not to matter much from a PageRank perspective.

- Fewer links per page will pass more PageRank per link.
- Also, pages on your site will receive fewer links from other pages on your site.

There is a fixed amount of PageRank available to your site.  You can distribute it to your pages via internal links.   The number of links you use per page doesn't change the amount that is available, not will it change the amount of PageRank that most of your pages end up getting from external links.

If there is some particular page that you want to rank better, it is possible to adjust PageRank going to it from internal links and help it rank better.   Removing other links from the pages linking to it would be one way of doing so.  However, it is usually easier to create more links to that page from additional pages that hadn't linked to it before.

It is also tempting to try to remove internal links to pages that don't matter for SEO.  Why would you link and pass PageRank to pages that you don't want to rank?  For example, if you have pages in robots.txt, will it help the rest of your site to remove the links to them?   From my experiments, it appears not to.   I've never been able to increase rankings to my site as a whole by "preserving" PageRank by removing links to pages that Google doesn't index.

Comment: In my experience, removing links to saturate PageRank only yields a visible impact on rankings when it is the homepage that is the source of dilution. I have also never observed rankings improve after removing links to pages that aren't indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Stephen's answer makes several great points, and overall provides great advice. I agree fully.

However, Michael Scott also hints and something that I believe is important to mention here.

> Personally, I link to anything on my site that is related to the topic I'm talking about.

One of the ways that search engines try to understand a web page is through the semantics of its internal links. The anchor text and surrounding text in close proximity before and after the anchor are used to understand the meaning and context of a page and those it links to.

Specifically, the internal links in the main content of a page are what is most important. Your navigation, footer, etc are not of much semantic concern.

Now, you don't want to over do it as too many internal links can signal low quality. Link when it is useful and relevant, and use natural language in your anchor text.